# Should I upvote answers that are helpful but don't quite answer the question?

Tags: discussion, voting

When looking for a way to add padding to a [Titanium Picker](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker), I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592297/215384) that gave me what I need. However, it doesn't seem to answer the actual question, as noted in the comment by [Ahmed Galal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457252/ahmed-galal). I want to upvote it as I did find it helpful but I am hesitant because it would imply that the answer answers the given question.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: The only criteria implied by upvoting is *"This answer is useful"*...that's it. Feel free to vote as you wish.

Comment: Note that sometimes you land via search on question that have almost nothing directly related to your problem but gives you answer the way you mentioned. Consider if edited to include reason you've landed there is appropriate or at least if comment about it would help future visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the tooltip says: "This answer is useful", so if it is useful to you, go ahead and upvote it.

[image]

Whether or not it is really the right answer to the OP's question, that's where the Accepted answer is for.

Comment: There are some that are upvoted and accepted and don't answer the question! e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32672779/558352

Comment: @BradThomas the OP accepted his/her own answer. There's not much we can do about that, do we?

Answer (score 7):

So at the end of the day, it's up to nobody besides you to come to the decision as to whether or not you think that the answer is useful, even if it doesn't answer the question.  That said, here are some thing that you may want to consider:

Is the answer useful if it fails to actually answer the question?  Even if the post contains correct information, and even if you happened to learn something from it, keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help people find answers to questions, and when the answer doesn't answer the question, some people may coincidentally also be interested in the question that the answer is actually answering, but lots of people aren't.

On the flip side, many people are going to post answers that are designed to solve the root problem that the person asking the question has, without answering the literal question asked.  In some, but not all, of such cases it's reasonable that others with that same question are likely to have a very similar root cause, and would thus also be helped by seeing that answer as well, even though it doesn't answer the question.

So in general, there are going to be cases where an answer fails to technically answer the question, but it's still going to be an effect answer anyway for people looking for an answer to the posted question, and in those cases, the answer is a useful answer to the question (whether technically correct or not).  But when the post isn't providing an answer to people with the same question being asked, even if it happens to provide unrelated information that someone who coincidentally is also interested that other topic might find useful, then that answer isn't really a useful answer to the posted question.  That same post could *become* a useful answer if moved onto a better question, but it's not really useful *where it is*.  Context is very relevant; answers cannot be evaluated in isolation; their usefulness is dependent on the context of the question they are posted to.